# detect incomplete 32 bit binary data

Tags: c, binaryfiles, eof, file-handling

I have a binary file from which I need to read 32 bit patterns- In the event if the EOF is reached such that its less than 32 bits - I need to error out saying unexpected eof else just break. I tried a lot but I am unable to get the incomplete bytes detecting part working. Can someone provide some pointer how to achieve it ? I did thought of exploring one byte at a time byte[0] and evaluating if its EOF but didnt work.

```
   for (;;)
   {
     bytes_read = fread(buffer, 4, 1, inFile);
     if (bytes_read == 1)
     {
      // perform the task
     }
     else
     {
         // detect if its incomplete sequence or EOF and output appropriately
     }
   }
```

P.S : Editing fread as per comment -

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(char)` as the number of items to read?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. EOF token doesn't fit into a `char`. You're trying to read more than one char and still comparing if you only read one?

Comment: You do not have "hexadecimal" in the file; you have **binary**.   Hexadecimal consists of **text** like `3D0F`, which is **four** characters denoting 16 bits or two bytes. Also note that `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition, and it is inappropriate to use it for another reason: the third argument to `fread` represents the number of elements to read, of the size given by the second argument. `sizeof (char)` isn't a good way to express the concept of "give me one element".

Comment: @Kaz - Thanks for making me aware about the binary part and differentiation with hexadecimal - I get the fread part - problem is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html - doesnt mention do's and don'ts of how to represent the 1 - so I naively chose sizeof(char) -

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - Can you please put a snippet of what would be best way to achieve it - as I am unable to get my head around it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tells `fread` to read one record, containing 4 bytes, from the file. If the record is incomplete, it will return 0 (0 records read, error). If the record is missing (at end of file), it will also return 0 (0 records read, normal situation). You must adjust your code to distinguish these cases, by having `fread` return `4` (bytes) instead.

If it's impossible to read 4 bytes at the end of file, you want `fread` to output less than 4. To have this behavior, you should tell fread to read in units of 1 byte:

```
bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, 4, inFile);
```

Then look at the number:

```
if (bytes_read == 4)
{
    // perform the task
}
else if (bytes_read > 0)
{
    // bad file format - not a multiple of 4 bytes
}
else if (bytes_read == 0)
{
    break; // success
}
else // bytes_read = -1
{
    // general file error
}
```

Comment: ahh - if only I could think - I would have swapped the number of bytes from 4,1 to 1,4 of fread -Thanks a ton .. that solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

`fread` doesn't return the number of bytes read, it returns the number of items, whose size is given in the second argument, were read. Since you're asking for it to read 1 item; if it encounters EOF before reading all the bytes of the item, it should return `0`.

Although `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`, it's not appropriate to use it in a context where you're not actually referring to the size of something. In this case, it's just a count, so you should use `1`.

```
size_t items_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, inFile);
if (items_read == 1) {
    // perform the task
} else if (feof(inFile)) {
    // got EOF before reading the last number
} else if (ferror(inFile)) {
    // got an error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I tried what you suggested but its not giving out output as expected .. sample input  parameter 64702E63 0D0A  .. with 0D0A I expected it to give error and break and in event it was 0D0A0000 - no error

Comment: If you're reading hex numbers, not binary, you shouldn't use `sizeof(unsigned long)` in the first place. `sizeof (unsigned long)` is probably 4 bytes, but the hex representation is 8 bytes.

Comment: Maybe you should be using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` to read a line and parse the number in it.

Comment: I need to read 32 bits at a time - I tried using fgets but not sure how it would solve the problem ?

Comment: Your title says you're reading binary data, but the first line of the question says you're reading hexadecimal. Please clarify the question.

Comment: It should be 4 (as the question suggests) or maybe `uint32_t`, certainly not `unsigned long`!